# How to convert octal to decimal in the different form without using APIs?

Tags: java, decimal, octal

I tried to convert octal to decimal and I got some output but I am not satisfied with it. Can anyone give an idea how to convert a different model without using API-s?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   System.out.print("Enter the number to convert");
   Scanner ss =new Scanner(System.in);
   int a = ss.nextInt(); 
   int b = ss.nextInt();
   int c = ss.nextInt();
   int d = ss.nextInt();
   int  temp =(a*(8*8*8));
   int  temp1 =(b*(8*8));
   int  temp2 =(c*(8));
   int  temp3 =(d*(1));
   System.out.println("The decimal is " +"\n"  + (temp +temp1 +temp2 +temp3)) 
 }
```

Comment: Check that Scanner.nextInt() method will read an integer, not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
BufferedReader reader = 
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String oct = reader.readLine();
int i= Integer.parseInt(oct,8);
System.out.println("Decimal:=" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I havn't try this but try to get a logic,

take input in a string then

```
String s ; //for input
String answer ="";
for(a=0,b=s.length-1;b>=0;b--)
{
int digit =Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(a));
int ans = (int)(digit * Math.pow(8,b));
answer+=ans;
a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my version is something you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    String numberString = sc.nextLine();
    int[] eachNumbers = new int[numberString.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < eachNumbers.length; i++){
        eachNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberString.substring(i, i+1));
    }

    int digit = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < eachNumbers.length; i++){
        if(eachNumbers.length > 1){
            digit += (eachNumbers[i] * Math.pow(8, eachNumbers.length - (i+1)));
        }else{
            digit += (eachNumbers[i] * 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The Octal " + numberString + " as Decimal is " + digit);
}
```

I know there is alot that can be made better but I'm still learning and wanted to help you :)